# Arithmetic operator return type

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char a = 10, b = 100;
    std::cout<<sizeof(a-b)<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Output: `4`

What is the return data type?

Comment: Isn't 4 the difference of the number of bits required to represent 100 and 10 i.e. 6 and 2 ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: I think it would be beneficial to you if you posted that as a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arithmetic is always performed at least with `int` precision in C++.  `a` and `b` are both promoted to `int` and the result of the subtraction is of type `int`.

There are a set of rules used to determine the type used for an arithmetic operation; MSDN has [a handy table listing the rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx).

Comment: Aren't they promoted to `unsigned int`'s?

Comment: @James: Is this part of the standard?

Comment: @Jacob:  Yes.  The rules are found at the beginning of clause 5 ("Expressions") in the C++ language standard.  The rules are the same as those described on MSDN (well, MSDN adds `long long` to the list, which isn't present in C++03 but is present in C++0x).

Comment: @nightcracker:  No, they are promoted to `int`.

Comment: +1. And on platforms where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)` (not that I have ever worked on one...), that computation would promote it to `unsigned int`. On 16bit boxes with `16bit` int, you will have `unsigned short` be promoted to `unsigned int` likewise (not that I have ever worked on one either).

Comment: Can you point out which section of clause 5? It came up in a discussion last week, but we couldn't find anything guaranteeing the promotion to int.

Comment: @dauphic:  It's at 5/9 in both C++03 and C++0x.  The paragraph begins "Many binary operators..."  4.5 ("Integral promotions") and 4.7 ("Integral conversions") are also relevant (for this question, the integral promotions are the most relevant of all those sections).

Comment: Thanks. I misinterpreted the 'can be' in 4.5 as allowing the compiler to promote, but not requiring. I guess it's required when mixed with 'The integral promotion shall be performed.'